# Leaflet JS - Draw rectangle and filter circle markers in the rectangle and update HTML table with only those markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I have a leaflet map which has circleMarkers plotted by longitude and latitude using the markers array coming from an AJAX REQUEST. This all works fine. I am trying to work on drawing a rectangle around a set of markers already on the map this should filter the circle markers on the leaflet map and the HTML table on the page.

The below is how I add the circle marker to the map:

```
var cMarkers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i) {

    var marker =  L.circleMarker([markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng], { radius: 2, color: getColor(markers[i].type) })
        .bindPopup('<a href="' + markers[i].url + '" target="_blank">' + markers[i].number+ '</a>')
        .addTo(map);
    cMarkers.push(marker);
}
```

The below is the code I have to draw the rectangle around a set of markers but currently it doesnt do anything except when I hover over the rectangle it alerts me the long and lat of the rectangle. The rectangle remains on the map and doesnt filter or do anything except draw a rectangle.

```
 // Initialise the FeatureGroup to store editable layers
var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(editableLayers);

var drawPluginOptions = {
    position: 'topright',
    draw: {
        // disable toolbar item by setting it to false
        polyline: false,
        circle: false, // Turns off this drawing tool
        polygon: false,
        rectangle: true,
        marker: false,
    },
    edit: {
        featureGroup: editableLayers, //REQUIRED!!
        remove: true
    }
};

// Initialise the draw control and pass it the FeatureGroup of editable layers
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw(drawPluginOptions);
map.addControl(drawControl);

var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(editableLayers);

map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

    if (type === 'rectangle') {
        layer.on('mouseover', function () {
            alert(layer.getLatLngs());
        });
    }

    editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
});
```

The jquery snippet I use to create the HTML table is based on the markers array :

```
var html = '<table id="tabledt">';
html += '<thead>';
html += '<tr>';
var flag = 0;
$.each(markers[0], function (index, value) {
    html += '<th>' + index + '</th>';
});
html += '</tr>';
html += '</thead>';
html += '<tbody>';
$.each(markers, function (index, value) {
    html += '<tr data-id="' + index + '">';
    $.each(value, function (index2, value2) {
        html += '<td>' + value2 + '</td>';
    });
    html += '</tr>';
});
html += '</tbody>';
html += '</table>';
$('#dvTable').html(html);

$('#tabledt th:nth-child(1),#tabledt td:nth-child(1)').remove();
```

Currently the page loads with all markers on the map and the table has the data. I then want to draw a rectangle and this filter to those markers and update the html table.
How can I retrieve only the markers in the rectangle drawn and filter these on the leaflet map and html table on the page?

Answer (score 1):

With this function you can get the CircleMarkers they are under the rectangle bounds:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (event) {
    var layer = event.layer;
    
    if(layer && layer instanceof L.Rectangle){
        getCircleMarkers(layer.getBounds());
    }
    
    editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
});

function getCircleMarkers(bounds){
    var layers = [];
    editableLayers.eachLayer((layer)=>{
    if(layer && layer instanceof L.CircleMarkers && !(layer instanceof L.Circle)){ //only circleMarkers, exclude Circles
        if(bounds.contains(layer.getLatLng())){
        layers.push(layer)
      }
    }
  });
  return layers;
}
```

In the example you have to use circles: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/qpL90vh6/

Comment: Looking at the example JS Fiddle. I drew a rectangle and circle (tried both) over a marker and the console comes back as an empty array []. Cant see how the fiddle is working unless I am doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Yeah you have to draw circles instead of circlemarkers and then you can get the layers (circles) with the rectangle

Comment: My code has circle markers already plotted on the map. I then want to draw rectangles over the circle markers. Sorry I don’t quite understand why I would draw circles ? The function above is using L.circlemarker so should it not find the circle marker already on the map?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
The function is not working for me I get the above error

Comment: @roa765 I can't reproduce this, but maybe it helps when first checking if layer is valid also `if(layer && layer instanceof L.Rectangle)`

Comment: leaflet.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventParent' of undefined
This is when trying to draw the rectangle I get the following error

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked to print me the list of ones in the rectangle. Just need to figure out how to filter these out on the map now:

```
     new L.Control.Draw({
            draw: {
                marker: false,
                polygon: false,
                polyline: false,
                rectangle: true,
                circle: false
            },
            edit: false
        }).addTo(map);
    
        L.Rectangle.include({
            contains: function (markers) {
                var markersContained = markers.filter(marker => { return this.getBounds().contains(marker.getLatLng()) === true; })
        
                return markersContained;
            }
        });

   map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (geometry) {
        // Set an array containing all the markers
        var markers = jsonToArray(layerGroup._layers);
        var result = geometry.layer.contains(markers);
        console.log('result => ', result);
    });
```